# What is the best way to manage a client side database in GWT based clients?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am working on a GWT client. My application needs to store some data at the client. I want to put that data in the browser cache. SO, this data will be available to be used(at least for current browser session) by subsequent requests.

Please suggest me what options I have got? How should I design my client code? What challenges I will face?

I got to know about two options, one of using Google's `Gears` and other is using `HTML5`. But these both are not widely supported in all the browsers. Can I think of having a new Data Layer in my project, that will handle the database needs. And I will put my static data in the memory itself?

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML5 [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). Gears is no longer being updated, and the HTML5 standard is preferred.

When you use Web Storage you will be storing your data on the user's disk, so that browser and computer crashes won't destroy your data.